# How to output my images into html documents using python (Django)

Tags: python, django, screenshot

please i need help with my django project. The code i have here is taking screenshots and saving it in my media folder so i want to output the pictures in my html page but it's giving me issues, i think i'm missing a lot.

Here is my python code which is taking the screenshots

````
from django.http import HttpResponse
import time,random,pyautogui
from django.db import models
import sys,os
from shots.models import pictures
from shots.forms.forms import DocumentForm
from django.conf import settings


def button(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def output(request):
    while True:
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        name = random.randrange(1,1000)
        full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
        filepath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\shots'
        full_path = filepath + full_name 
        saver = myScreenshot.save(full_path)
        # generate a random time between 120 and 300 sec
        random_time = random.randrange(3,6)
        # wait between 120 and 300 seconds (or between 2 and 5 minutes)
        time.sleep(random_time)
        myScreenshots2 = []
        myScreenshots2.append(saver)
        # return (myScreenshots2)
        return HttpResponse(request,'task.html',saver)

def stopshot(request):
    os.system("pause")```
````

Comment: You realize that the screenshots you take are from the *server* machine, not from the browser/client? Likely the server has no logical "screen", hence it will likely even error when you take a screenshot.

Comment: i don't understand you please can you explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python code runs on the server, and user is using a client to connect to the server.When you want to take screenshots it should be done by client not the server, since server is not users computer.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots) to see how you can take screenshots from client using js.